# SQL - select surrounding records of the one fulfil a condition

Tags: sql, window-functions, amazon-athena, presto

I have the following table:

```
epochTime,id,counter1,value
123,Alpha,2,2
124,Beta,0,3
135,Alpha,0,1
112,Alpha,0,5
150,Alpha,0,-1
225,Beta,1,2
228,Beta,1,0
300,Beta,0,2
```

I want to select all records with counter1 > 0 and the record after that, partitioning by id and order by epochTime (the requirement similar to Unix "grep -A 1" command)
So the expected result from the data above would be

```
epochTime      id    counter1       value
      123   Alpha           2           2
      135   Alpha           0           1
      225    Beta           1           2
      228    Beta           1           0
      300    Beta           0           2
```

I am using AWS Athena, and got the following query, which works as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id,
        epochTime,
        counter1,
        value,
        first_value(counter1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY id
            ORDER BY epochTime
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS preCounter
    FROM testsql
) WHERE counter1 > 0 OR preCounter > 0
```

However, I see two problems with the query:

- It is a nested query
- I needed to create a dummy column (preCounter). If the requirements on the WHERE condition become more complex (i.e: conditions on multiple columns), I would need to create multiple dummy columns

  1. Are there better solutions (better performance, simpler query, ...) for me?
  2. What if counter1 is the number of following records I need to select?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(counter) over (partition by id order by epochtime) as prev_counter
      from testseql t
     ) t
where counter > 0 or prev_counter > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon

Lag, in this specific example, would make the query less complex by avoiding that "between row and row".

But let's say I need to select 2 subsequent records (instead of 1 as in my example), lag won't work. Lag also doesn't help when my WHERE condition is on multiple columns.

Comment: @Averell . . . "I want to select all records with counter1 > 0 and the record after that, partitioning by id and order by epochTime ".  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.